# Temporary MEDIA_ROOT for testing not working

Tags: python, django

For the purpose of testing user media uploads, I have created a temporary MEDIA_ROOT in my test module so that the development directory doesn't become polluted with mock images.

I have stumbled upon this and how Django happens to achieve the same task of creating/destroying a temporary MEDIA_ROOT:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/file_uploads/tests.py#L26

When the tests are ran however, I get the following error

```
\test_models.py", line 17, in <module>
    MEDIA_ROOT = mkdtemp(prefix="media/")
  File \Python\Python37\lib\tempfile.py", line 366, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
FileNotFoundError: 
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Temp\\media/0_axhu0o'
```

How can I get the test to pass so that path of image file is stored relative to the temporary MEDIA_ROOT with that directory having the same name of *media/*?

**tests.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = mkdtemp(prefix="media/")
@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=MEDIA_ROOT)
class TestPhotoModel(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpData(self):
        os.makedirs(MEDIA_ROOT)
        user = User.objects.create_user("Testuser")
        test_image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            "test_image.jpg",
            content=b"",
            content_type="image/jpeg"
        )

        freezer = freeze_time("2020-12-31")
        freezer.start()

        data = {
            "source": test_image,
            "title": "Test Image",
            "upload_date": datetime.date.today,
            "likes": 0,
            "photographer": user
        }
        self.photo_instance = Photo.objects.create(**data)

    def test_photo_count(self):
        self.assertEqual(Photo.objects.count(), 1)

    def test_image_upload_path(self):
        self.assertEqual(
           self.photo_instance.source.path, 
           "media/uploads/2020/12/31/test_image.jpg"
        )

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        rmtree(MEDIA_ROOT)
        super().tearDownClass()
```